# Tables/records created to GCloud DB via node-postgres not visible in psql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, node-postgres

I have a Postgres database in Google Cloud which I am able to connect to and create tables in via psql and 3rd db tools like DBeaver.

I can also 'successfully' create tables and insert data via node-postgres. The data I create via node-postgres I can also query via node-postgres.

The issue is that I cannot locate any of the data created via node-postgres through psql or DBeaver.

For example, I created a table 'test1' via node-postgres and inserted a few records which I am able to then query via node-postgres. However, when I connect to the same DB in psql and list my tables, this new table is nowhere to be found.

Anyone know the reason why data created via node-postgres seems to be unreachable via other means?

Comment: What are the sentences that you are using from `node-postgres` to create and read? Maybe the rows are not being committed?

Comment: By GCloud DB you mean Cloud SQL?

Comment: @A.Queue yes, Cloud SQL for Postgres

@Mangu I'm using an insert statement like the one below. When I later query the same table via node-postgres, I get results back. I just don't see anything via psql or 3rd party DB tools. 

`client.query('INSERT INTO test14 (text, complete) VALUES ($1, $2)',
            ['test1414', true]);`

Comment: Could you share the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?